# How can I contact a specific user

Tags: support

I'm new here and it was suggested to me to ask this here. There was a [particular user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/292527/iv) who's answers and questions came up more than once when researching a couple math related topics and I was hoping to ask if they would like to collaborate with myself and other mathematicians on furthering a particular research area.

So, I signed up for an account here, but then there appears to be no messaging system. Then I figured maybe if I left a comment it would alert them, but it won't let me comment on their posts. How could I contact a specific user? Maybe there is a way to start a chat room and invite them or something along those lines?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are users pingable from questions/answers?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3131/are-users-pingable-from-questions-answers)

Comment: Just to make sure, do you know you're on Meta.MO, not [Meta.MSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com), although you appear to be asking about an MSE user?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to contact a MathOverflow user?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3634/how-to-contact-a-mathoverflow-user)

Comment: Since you have mentioned chat, I will add link to this post on [math.meta.se]: [How do I invite a user to chat?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22037) But you should keep in mind that you can only create a chatroom after you have at least [100 reputation points](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/chat-rooms). To use an existing chatroom, [20 reputation points is enough](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/chat).

Comment: Some people provide contact details / a link to their professional homepage in their profile. People who don't do so may prefer not to be contacted by other people from the site. You can comment on other peoples' posts once you have gathered 50 points, cf. https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/comment .